# Неправильно работает getdate()

Tags: php

```
 function Date_To_Show($value){

            $time           = explode(' ',$value);
            $date = $time[0];
                    $dateconvert = explode('-',$date);
                    $year  = $dateconvert[0];
                    $month = $dateconvert[1];
                    $day   = $dateconvert[2];
            $time = $time[1];
    return '0, 0, 0, '.ltrim($month,'0').', '.ltrim($day,'0').', '.$year."";
    }

$arrayDate = getdate(mktime(Date_To_Show($_GET['date'])));
echo  $arrayDate['wday'];
```

На все числа показывает субботу.(т.е. 6)

Comment: Кому должно? И каков формат date в запросе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может  быть Ваша функция просто должна была делать это

```
date("w",strtotime($_GET['date']))
```